# Webpack + eslint replace source change on linting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server

Running on webpack dev server with a string replacement plugin that does a replacement based [on a function](https://github.com/jamesandersen/string-replace-webpack-plugin/blob/master/loader.js#L19). I am finding the value of the replacement overwritten my source file .

My Dev server configuration is this:

```
const devServer = (options) => {
  return {
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      inline: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
      host: options.host,
      port: options.port,
      historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
        multiStep: true
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

The string replacement plugin configuration is:

```
  const constants = (data) => {
    return {
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
              replacements:[
                {
                  pattern:/\`CONSTANT_(.*)\`/g,
                  replacement:(match,p1,offset,string)=>{
                    console.log('MATCH '+p1)
                    const keys = p1.split('.')
                    let current = data
                    keys.forEach((key)=>{
                      current = current[key]
                    })
                    console.log('Replacing '+p1+' with '+current)
                    return `'${current}'`
                  }
                }
              ]
            })
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new StringReplacePlugin()
      ]
    }
  }
```

The entry/ouptut values are:

```
const base = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(PATHS.app, './index.jsx')
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  }
}
```

Is there any reason why webpack dev server would be changing files on source?

**EDIT: 1** Added JS part:

```
const js = (paths) => {
  const cacheDir = (process.env.CACHE_DIRECTORY ? process.env.CACHE_DIRECTORY : 'true')
  return {

    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loaders: [
            `babel?cacheDirectory=${cacheDir}`, // presets on .babelrc
            'eslint-loader?fix'
          ],
          include: paths
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 2** The cause seesm to be the eslint-loader?fix, when removed the appropriate behaviour is achieved. Now I am seeking how to prevent that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the eslint-loader?fix before every change prevented that.